# Count of unique values per group as new column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I would like to count the unique observations by a group in a pandas dataframe and create a new column that has the unique count. Importantly, I would not like to reduce the rows in the dataframe; effectively performing something similar to a window function in SQL.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'uID': ['James', 'Henry', 'Abe', 'James', 'Henry', 'Brian', 'Claude', 'James'],
         'mID': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C']
})

df.groupby('mID')['uID'].nunique()
```

Will get the unique count per group, but it summarises (reduces the rows), I would effectively like to do something along the lines of:

```
df['ncount'] = df.groupby('mID')['uID'].transform('nunique')
```

(this obviously does not work)

It is possible to accomplish the desired outcome by taking the unique summarised dataframe and joining it to the original dataframe but I am wondering if there is a more minimal solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `GroupBy.transform('nunique')`

On `v0.23.4`, your solution works for me.

```
df['ncount'] = df.groupby('mID')['uID'].transform('nunique')
df
      uID mID  ncount
0   James   A       5
1   Henry   B       2
2     Abe   A       5
3   James   B       2
4   Henry   A       5
5   Brian   A       5
6  Claude   A       5
7   James   C       1
```

---

#### `GroupBy.nunique` + `pd.Series.map`

Additionally, with your existing solution, you could `map` the series back to `mID`:

```
df['ncount'] = df.mID.map(df.groupby('mID')['uID'].nunique())
df
      uID mID  ncount
0   James   A       5
1   Henry   B       2
2     Abe   A       5
3   James   B       2
4   Henry   A       5
5   Brian   A       5
6  Claude   A       5
7   James   C       1
```

Answer (score 3):

You are very close!

```
df['ncount'] = df.groupby('mID')['uID'].transform(pd.Series.nunique)

      uID mID  ncount
0   James   A       5
1   Henry   B       2
2     Abe   A       5
3   James   B       2
4   Henry   A       5
5   Brian   A       5
6  Claude   A       5
7   James   C       1
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, on my original data I get a ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 29101 elements, new values have 29457 elements, i'm not even creating a new column just assigning to a new variable. Your solution does answer the question, any ideas on this error?
EDIT: NA values were the culprit here.

Comment: @ZeroStack, that might be this bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17093 I would try df.fillna(0).groupby(...), and if that works, investigate further how to fill any missing values in the columns `mID` and/or `uID`.